# How to make a cdn for my fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I have a problem loading fonts from a subdomain.

I want to host them on a ftp that has an address like http://static.mydomain.com/fonts.

Then I want to load it from several subsites: http://subsite1.mydomain.com and http://subsite2.mydomain.com.

The problem is: if I include the fonts with a font-face property like that:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: NeutonBold;
    src: url('http://static.mydomain.com/fonts/Neuton-Bold.ttf');
}
```

Then I receive this security error from the browser:

```
Font from origin '...' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I really would like to avoid to duplicate the fonts on all the subsites ...

Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The conclusion you can infer from **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** is that it is possible and you accomplish it by adding an appropriate HTTP header called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

Comment: thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález it was the solution !

Answer (score -2):

See what happens if you put the font-family: underneath, like this:

```
@font-face {
    src: url('http://static.mydomain.com/fonts/Neuton-Bold.ttf');
    font-family: NeutonBold;
}
```

Comment: What kind of an answer is this, lol